# Workout session causing app crashes with multiple paired Apple Watches

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, watchos, watchconnectivity

## Problem

I am developing an application that can track workout sessions for multiple paired Apple Watches (multiple watches paired to a single phone). I have implemented Watch Connectivity for multiple watches as per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession), and that part of the application seems to be working okay. The application allows the user to initiate a workout session and pulls data from HealthKit so the user can view it in the future. I am having an issue with the application crashing (or at the very least, the `handleActiveWorkoutRecovery` method is called) after starting a workout following a pairing switch of the watches. As a sample timeline to what occurs:

| Time (minutes) | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | User starts workout session on Watch 1 |
| 5 | User stops workout session on Watch 1 |
| 5 | User switches pairing from Watch 1 to Watch 2 |
| 5 | User starts workout session on Watch 2 |
| 6 | The application "crashes" on Watch 2 |

I would include Crash logs, but the crash does not seem to show up anywhere. I have tried finding the logs through the organizer for TestFlight versions, and manually through `sysdiagnose` and the `Devices and Simulators` tab in XCode, but they just aren't anywhere, leaving me to hypothesize that this is not actually a crash (or at least that crash logs are not being generated).

## What I have tried

I initially hypothesized there was some issue with the way I had implemented WCSession, but all three of the required methods `session(_:activationDidCompleteWith:error:)`, `sessionDidBecomeInactive(_:)` and `sessionDidDeactivate(_:)` have been implemented in the code appropriately, as have all delegates. I also tried switching multiple times without starting a workout session to see if the application would crash, but it did not. I do not think this is the problem.

I also hypothesized that perhaps I was not ending the workout sessions appropriately and maybe the issue was something related to that. However, I am calling the appropriate `.end()` and `.stop()` methods for the [workout session](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/running_workout_sessions) and [HealthKit queries](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614173-stop) respectively. Additionally, I can restart the session on a single device after stopping it immediately, and it does not cause any issues. I do not think this is the problem either.

## Current hypothesis

Currently, I hypothesize that the problem lies somewhere in starting the session too early after switching. So for example, while doing testing, I discovered that this timeline of events **DOES NOT** cause a crash

| Time (minutes) | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | User starts workout session on Watch 1 |
| 5 | User stops workout session on Watch 1 |
| 5 | User switches pairing from Watch 1 to Watch 2 |
| 10 | User starts workout session on Watch 2 |

However, this timeline of events, **DOES** cause a crash.

| Time (minutes) | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | User starts workout session on Watch 1 |
| 5 | User stops workout session on Watch 1 |
| 10 | User switches pairing from Watch 1 to Watch 2 |
| 10 | User starts workout session on Watch 2 |
| 11 | The application "crashes" on Watch 2 |

Notice in the previous test I had waited 5 minutes before initiating the session on the newly paired watch, and in this one, I waited 5 minutes before switching the pairing, but start the workout session immediately after the switch. To be absolutely clear, I always wait for the switch to complete (a tick mark appears in the watch app on the phone when the switch is complete) before starting a tracking session.

## Question

To me, it seems like there is something going on after switching for at least a few minutes wherein starting a session will cause a crash. Unfortunately, I do not know what that is, so am wondering if there is a chain of events that occur after switching the watch pairing which will cause the workout session to crash if it starts too early. Right now the only workaround I can think of is not allowing the user to initiate a workout session for a specific period of time after a watch switch, but I want to know if there is some sort of event that I can tie that functionality to, instead of just blocking the user for a period of time.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. You also need to include the crash log in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but: your use of HealthKit will not be relevant here, unless it's simply contributing to your control flow in a way that's causing some other mismatch. HealthKit workout sessions are fully independent on different devices, and so session control on one cannot affect sessions on another.